# Formview cascading dropdown issue

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, formview, cascadingdropdown

I'm working on a Formview where in the EditTemplate, I have 1 dropdownlist dependent on another dropdownlist value.
I've looked at some examples and have found this one to be the most concise and I am working off of it:

http://mikepope.com/blog/AddComment.aspx?blogid=1629
It's pretty straight-forward but it's not working for my ddl. Can you tell me what I am missing or not implementing properly? I have removed some of the code in order to troubleshoot but still, nothing. For example, I am not setting the selectedValue as nothing is being returned...

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

HTML:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
...
...
...
<tr>
 <td colspan="6" align="left">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddTeams" runat="server" CssClass="myDropDownIndent" DataSourceID="sqlGetTeams" DataTextField="Team" DataValueField="Team" SelectedValue='<%# DetermineTeamValue(Eval("Team")) %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
  </asp:DropDownList>
 </td>

 <td colspan="4" align="left">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownOwner" runat="server" CssClass="myDropDown" DataSourceID="sqlGetMembers2" DataTextField="EmployeeName" DataValueField="EmployeeName"                                                                                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
  </asp:DropDownList>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGetMembers2" runat="server"                                         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectDashboardConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="usp_GetMembers" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>                
   <asp:Parameter Name="Type" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="TeamID" />                                            
 </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>

</td>
</tr>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub fvTask_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles fvTask.DataBound

            If fvTask.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Edit Then
                Dim dv As System.Data.DataRowView = fvTask.DataItem
                Dim ddTeams2 As DropDownList = fvTask.FindControl("ddTeams")

                Dim DropDownOwner As DropDownList = fvTask.FindControl("DropDownOwner")
                Dim a As String = "A"                
                Dim dsc As SqlDataSource = fvTask.FindControl("sqlGetMembers2")

                dsc.SelectParameters("TeamID").DefaultValue = String.Empty
                dsc.SelectParameters("Type").DefaultValue = String.Empty
                DropDownOwner.DataBind()

                'If Not IsDBNull(dv("EmployeeName")) Then
                '    DropDownOwner.SelectedValue = dv("EmployeeName")
                'End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrMessage = ex.ToString
        End Try

    End Sub
```

So, my 2nd dropdownlist is null.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error? Why are you setting the select parameters to empty strings? From the code you are showing, those parameters never get a value.

Comment: I was setting the Select parameters to empty just to test this out (the stored proc accepts null values and returns all basically).

Comment: What happens when you put real values in there? If you are testing with null, you may need to use [CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.cancelselectonnullparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I should have followed up sooner...What I did was change the sqldatasource and created one with a control parameter which is assigned to the 1st dropdown. That resolved it. This would leave me to believe that the issue was around the datasource and the data that I was sending it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue. I appreciate it.